# how to delete row from grid ( CRUD ) in PHP without using jquery & $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I want to delete row from grid without using jquery and $_GET. because I dont want to show Row ID.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 

$readsql= "select * from country";
$readresult=$conn->query($readsql);
if ($readresult->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $readresult->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['country_id'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['country_name'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>'. $row['country_phon'] . '</td>';                      
     echo '<td width=250>';
     echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success abc"  data-toggle="modal" data-cid='. $row['country_id'] .' data-cphone='.$row['country_phon'].' data-cname='.$row['country_name'].' >Update</button>';
     echo ' ';
     echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger del" name="delete" data-id='.$row['country_id'].'>Delete</button>';
     echo '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';  } echo "</table>";
   } else {
   echo "0 results";
   }?></form>
```

Comment: I'm confused. You close a `table`  - but you never start one. Btw, simply post the form to the same page, check if submit buttson is set, if yes, delete the data. shouldn't be to difficult.

Comment: You want hide the table row by the row ID ? Under what conditions the row would be hidden/deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the row, create a CSS class

```
.hidden { display:none;}
```

Then change the type of the delete button to button. Add an onclick attribute to the button:

onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.className= 'hidden'"

If you want to delete it from the data table, you will need to send some term to the server to identify the record.